# Loosing connection with Microsoft Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, connection, cloud, ssms

I'm having really frequent and occasional connection problems between my local instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio (SSMS) and my cloud Microsoft Azure SQL Database.

Sporadically, my SSMS reports **Disconnected** along with the following error message when asking queries:
`Msg 10054, Level 20, State 0, Line 0

A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)`

Unfortunately, Googling this problem doesn't give me any clue on how to solve it.

Facts:

- I don't have any bad or lousy internet connection. It is fast and stable!
- I don't have any problems connecting to other remote SQL Server
     Databases.
- My cloud Microsoft Azure SQL Database is just for learning purpose - there is not heavy load on it since I'm the only user.

Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been able to reproduce the same behavior with a fresh SQL database? I suggest firing up one with near identical setup (such as service tier, performance level, server, etc.) to get closer to the root cause.

What does the portal report when you get into a DISCONNECTED mode? If there is a correlation between what SSMS is stating and what the portal is stating, then we know the issue lies NOT locally on your machine or with SSMS.

Also, take a look at the following troubleshooting page to see if you can tease out more info:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1719.aspx

Comment: Thank's! I'll have to evaluate it before I can accept it as an an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but i can not comment bcs of SO crappy reputation system so:

To answer SteveSeow:

> What does the portal report when you get into a DISCONNECTED mode? If
>   there is a correlation between what SSMS is stating and what the
>   portal is stating, then we know the issue lies NOT locally on your
>   machine or with SSMS.

The portal reports that everything is OK. and i can reconnect after ~10 sec.

EDIT: OK means that there is some DTU load but it is under 50%.

**Also:** Not only SSMS is disconnected, my website running on azure also can not connect to the Database for this period of time. This fact alone should rule out any local issue i might have.